# Number with too many decimal places ends up in scientific notation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting a price from a 3rd party API which is returned in scientific notation. When I actually check this price on their site, its shown as 1.20 but the api returns 1.2052626e

I want to perform a multiplication with that price field and format it to a currency string but it always returns as 0.00 cause of that scientific notation. Is there any way I can turn this 1.2052626e into a 1.20 or to a fixed amount of decimals for all scientific notations returned by that api?

Comment: Just parseFloat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parseFloat` to convert it to a decimal number and then use the toFixed method on it.

```js
const res = "1.2052626e";
console.log(parseFloat("1.2052626e").toFixed(2)); // as string

console.log(+parseFloat("1.2052626e").toFixed(2)); // as number
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using toFixed until the very last moment when displaying the final result after all computation since you are losing precision in the middle of computation process.

Comment: @RickyMo sometimes we do need to convert it to certain no of decimal places in middle of computation or we will come across errors due to floating point for numbers like `0.1+0.2`

Comment: @RickyMo, Yes You are right. It seems SO only needs to show up to two decimal points with any calculations on it.

Comment: I tried the above snippet again on my case. The number is returned as a float already from the API, so when I do parseFloat on it again, it still the scientific notation as returned initially. When I cast it toString and then back to parseFloat its still scientific notation too